# ... finished {written/writing/to write/wrote} two compositions

Tags: licensing

I am just practising some english grammar related questions , here is the question I am confused about :

> Salman finished__________ two of his published compositions before his twelfth birthday.
>       A. Written
>       B. Writing
>       C. To write
>       D. Wrote

Its correct answer is **B. Writing**. But why should we select "writing", what's the logic or rule behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a **licensing** matter: each verb “licenses” or permits only specific kinds of clausal complement. The verb *finish* licenses gerund clauses but not infinitive or *that* clauses:

> <sup>ok</sup>Salman finished **writing** two compositions.
>   <sup>∗</sup> Salman finished **to write** two compositions.
>   <sup>∗</sup> Salman finished **that he wrote** two compositions.

By contrast, *begin* licenses both gerund and infinitive clauses:

> <sup>ok</sup>Salman began **writing** two compositions.
>   <sup>ok</sup>Salman began **to write** two compositions.
>   <sup>∗</sup> Salman began **that he wrote** two compositions.

Linguists have strained for a couple of generations to discern a “logic or rule” behind specific licenses, but I have not seen a convincing account. It’s just an idiomatic property of individual words, and you have to learn it word-by-word.

Click this [licensing](/questions/tagged/licensing) to see more questions involving licensing by verbs and words of other classes.

---

<sup>∗</sup> *marks an utterance as unacceptable*

Comment: Can you bit explain in easy words , licensing mean what ?

Comment: @ARG As explained in the first sentence, *license* is the technical term for "permit" or "allow".

Comment: @Hellion Thanks for catching my mistake - your edit was bumped by mine, which missed it.

Comment: I wondered if you were still actively improving your answer, but I went for the edit anyway just in case.  :-)